# Post a "Check out my order" to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm developing a site that allows a user to create an order for a product based on "One of those, one of those, three of them, that much of that" etc to end up with a shopping list them can print out and take to their local store and show to a Customer Adviser "I'd like this product with these items in please".

I'd also like to have a Like button or something similar where you can post your results to your Facebook account - "Look what I'm buying!" sort of thing. Maybe even a link back to the client website.

I'm ultra new to the Facebook API - is anything like this possible? Have seen similar sort of ideas with people like Levi; is it possible to send complex text data to Facebook in this way rather than just "Like" a page, as the page results will be different for different users?

Comment: You should read though the documentation and return here with a specific problem after you have tried something yourself.  People will not do your work for you...  All of what you listed **is** indeed possible with Facebook's Graph API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that.

1. Become an app developer. See: http://developers.facebook.com
2. Read thru the examples and other documentation at. http://developers.facebook.com/docs
3. Set up an app at: https://developers.facebook.com/apps
4. Get your feet wet by coding up some of the examples
5. Then get to work on your project's requirements and code up the solution.
6. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the "comment" Lix - as I pointed out I am ultra new to the Facebook API and didn't want to spend precious development hours going through documentation to find out the idea I had was not possible. I was asking the enlightened FB community if the idea was feasible so that I could go and look for it - if someone was kind enough (thanks DMCS) to provide a Yes and a link to what to look at so much the better. I certainly don't expect my developer peers to "do the work for me". Thanks again.

Comment: Good luck on your endeavors.  If you get stuck, come back and post up code examples and/or a link to something and we might be able to help.

Comment: Cheers DMCS - taking the plunge now :-)